# How to vertically and horizontally center div

Tags: html, css, center

I am facing a problem, how to center text (h1) inside div. I want the web page to be full screen and i achieved that with vh units.

```
.page { height: 100vh; 
        width: 100%;}
```

On that page i want div to be centered horizontally and vertically. I tried with

```
.div { top: 50%;
      left: 50%;}
```

but that just didnt do the trick. I also want this to be "resposive" si that it is centered on any screen.
I am looking to build something like this: http://www.anthonygoodisondesign.com/

Answer (score 8):

use css code as below;

```css
div{height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  }
```

```html
<div>  <h1>center me</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 40vh;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/pLb8aysd/

Comment: you can just use display flex: like .parent  { display: flex; align-items:center;justify-content:center;} this will  center its child horizontally and verticall